# How to store ECG data on apple healthkit?

Tags: ios, swift3, healthkit

I am new to IOS app development. I have been trying to learn how to work with Apple HealthKit API. So far, as an experiment I have managed to build a simple app which could store and retrieve data from the HealthKit such as blood type, heart rate etc (i can furnish the code if anyone needs it-it is already available on the internet). I am able to do this functionality because healthkitStore exposes these typeIdentifiers for the app developers. However, I am a bit lost when I want to create a new  typeIdentifier such for storing ECG/EKG on the healthKit? I want to feed ECG/EKG signals into my app and use the HealthKitStore to save these information. Am i missing something?I know I am slow, but i have searched a lot over the internet, but I could not find any specific solutions.  Is this not possible? But the whole point of opening the API to the developers is to create new apps with different features. 
I have no specific requirement as far as storing and retrieving ECG data is concerned, as i simply want to create a PoC without any constraints but focusing on the functionality.

Will I be wrong If i want to create the above by using

```
struct HKClinicalTypeIdentifier
```

and then use Clinical Record type identifier

```
static let labResultRecord: HKClinicalTypeIdentifier
```

Is this the correct direction?
Any direction, motivation or criticism is much welcomed.

Comment: Since the watch has an ecg function there must be an apple way to store and use this data without defining your own types. The documentation is worse than Apple's normally lousy standard though.

Comment: So I think the ECG as a TypeIdentifier is currently missing from the HealthKit API. Certainly, looking at the screenshots Apple has provided of the ECG functionality, it looks like it will have its own section in the Health app like Heart Rate, Heart Rate Variability and VO2 Max for example. I suspect that with WatchOS 5.1.2 there will also be a new iOS release change. These will likely have the api calls added. It’s odd though that Apple hasn’t got these changes into the beta first to allow developers to get support in their apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an alternate solution to the above issue. I am writing this so that if anyone has similar issue can take a similar approach if needed. 
Basically at the time of writing this thread, there are no ECG typeIdentifier available for developers to use. However, the way around it is to create a HKQauntiySample object and pass the ECG values as metadata. But the only issue that i am facing with such an approach is to do with the rate at which the live/historical ECG can be saved into the healthkit.

The sampling frequency for the ECG e.g is 200 Hz. I am not able to store the data with subsecond timestamp. It can only provide upto seconds of timestamp. Also, it seems, the maximum rate at which data can be stored using the above object is as low as 160Hz. Maybe this is a limitation of the interface, healtkitstore etc. I dont know. Hope this closes the issue.

Comment: Is there now a better/correct solution now that the ECG data is actually being stored in healthkit?

Comment: Not yet Dmitri. Apple has not released a type identifier for ECG. I am using metadata to store ECG data. This is only a hack and can never be considered as a production solution.

Comment: Do you know if there's been any changes in the Healthkit to add the type identifier?

Comment: The type identifier has been added in iOS 14 beta with Xcode 12

Comment: In iOS 14 you can find this - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogram

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 14 you can read ECG data using new API

[HKElectrocardiogramQuery Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkelectrocardiogramquery)

here is the sample code I used to retrieve ECG data:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast,end: Date.distantFuture,options: .strictEndDate)
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
        let ecgQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKObjectType.electrocardiogramType(), predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]){ (query, samples, error) in
            guard let samples = samples,
                let mostRecentSample = samples.first as? HKElectrocardiogram else {
                return
            }
            print(mostRecentSample)
            var ecgSamples = [(Double,Double)] ()
            let query = HKElectrocardiogramQuery(mostRecentSample) { (query, result) in
                
                switch result {
                case .error(let error):
                    print("error: ", error)
                    
                case .measurement(let value):
                    print("value: ", value)
                    let sample = (value.quantity(for: .appleWatchSimilarToLeadI)!.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.volt()) , value.timeSinceSampleStart)
                    ecgSamples.append(sample)
                    
                case .done:
                    print("done")
                }
            }
            self.healthMonitor.healthStore.execute(query)
        }
        
        
        healthMonitor.healthStore.execute(ecgQuery)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```