# How to read ECG data from HealthKit using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, healthkit

I am trying to read ECG data from HealthKit but it seems like Xamarin.iOS (I am using 13.18.2.1) does not support ECG data yet. I did not see ECG in HKQuantityTypeIdentifier enum. I could not find HKElectrocardiogram or HKElectrocardiogramQuery classes.

Have you ever worked with ECG and Xamarin Forms? Is it possible to implement a manual query? In this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535698/1944025 someone manually created an HKQuantiySample passing ECG values as metadata, but I am not sure if this is possible in Xamarin Forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On June 22, 2020, at the Apple Worldwide Developers Conference, Xcode version 12 was announced; a beta version was released the same day.

Those are new classes in Xcode `12.0.0 beta 1` that will be supported on `iOS 14 18A5319g` and above and thus are not currently supported in the production release of Xamarin.iOS. You can keep watch on the [github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios), [Xamarin.iOS release notes and API changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/) and the [official Xamarin Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/) for product announcements / releases.

**Wiki (xamarin/xamarin-macios) HealthKit iOS xcode12 beta1**

- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/HealthKit-iOS-xcode12-beta1

Comment: I have checked the links again and I can't really see the ECG classes in Xamarin.iOS 14.2. Do you know if ECG data is available yet?

Comment: @BurakCetin Via `HKSampleQuery` using the `HKObjectType` of `HKElectrocardiogramType`

Comment: Thank you very much!